# startup problem : the disk drive /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present

Tags: mount

During startup the message above pops up, it has something to do with mounting.

However if I don't choose any of the options and just wait, ubuntu loads normally.

I am using ubuntu as my only OS. How can I fix this?

I am really new to ubuntu, so I would really appreciate a step-by-step answer.

Alex

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T). Type `cat /etc/fstab`, and post the results. `cat` means catonecate - it shows what is in that file.

Comment: There is an open bug report about this on launchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1061190

Answer (score 0):

This made me double take the first time I saw it too.

This isn't really a problem, since everything still works. The script that sets up encryption is just impatient, and it will do what it is supposed to once cryptswap is ready. I suggest we leave alone and wait for the updates to fix it.