# Startup problem: the disk drive /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present (12.10)

Tags: 12.10, mount, startup, drive

This message is appearing during start up. I'm a bit of a Linux noob and have no idea, how to remedy this or what it even means. I also realise, this is almost an exact replica of a [question that has already been asked](https://askubuntu.com/q/197475/175814), however it has not been answered and I could not possibly describe the problem I'm having any more accurately than this.

If I just leave it, it loads after a bit, but once its done loading, I get several pop-ups asking, if I want to send bug reports. Is this related at all? Where do I start here?

Comment: Could you please link to the question that you are referring to so we can understand what you already looked at?

Comment: yeah no probs its;      http://askubuntu.com/questions/197475/startup-problem-the-disk-drive-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or-not

Comment: Any ideas with this guys?

Comment: In 12.04 this seems to be [the solution](http://punygeek.blogspot.nl/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html). Maybe you can try this?